# Problem mixing overflow-x, FireFox, and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, scrollto

First of all, this problem only happens in Firefox.

Check this example page to understand the problem:
-removed-

Select any page besides home. The window will scroll to page. You can then scroll down using the mouse wheel. This works fine. BUT if you grab the scroll bar on the right with your mouse it will jump back to the "home page" (the top left, first element, which is part of the ENTIRE page/website).

The offending code is:

> #content{

```
overflow-x: hidden; /* <<problem maker */
overflow-y: auto;
width:100%;
background-color:white;
position:relative;
height:400px;
float:left;
min-width: 900px;
```

> }

... if I unhide overflow-x (overflow-x: auto;) everything works properly, but I get an undesired horizontal scroll bar.

I am using the jquery ScrollTo plugin that is animating the position of the div inside #content to create the "sliding" effect. Apparently, because Firefox is "resetting" to the default load position, it doesn't think it should have ever allowed me to "slide" horizontally.

Is this a Firefox bug? Or a bug in the ScrollTo plugin? Or maybe even jQuery?

Any ideas of how to fix this? Workarounds ideas?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: uh did you fix this cos I'm not seeing a difference in behavior betwixt IE or FX or chrome

Comment: nope. Haven't fixed it. Tested it in FF on PC and Mac. Did you make sure you grabbed the scroll bar with the mouse? It scrolls with keys and mouse wheel just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:
Hide the scroll bar under another div. Lame, but works in my case.

Comment: It was remarkably difficult for me to find info about this, despite the fact that it seems like a pretty glaring FF bug!

Comment: shoot me an email if you want to chat about the problem: dave@desmoinesfreelancer.com

Answer (score 0):

Back in ye old 2005, this was solved as such
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/help/archive.php/o_t__t_1294__overflow-on-firefox.html

Comment: ... uh, not sure how that solves the problem. I am using divs.