# Stop Firefox resetting horizontal scroll position when overflow is "hidden"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, overflow, scrollto

I have a horizontally scrolling div with sections inside. I'm using [Ariel Flesler's scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin to scroll from one section to another.

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/carienf/qZeEe/

The fiddle works perfectly in IE 9, Safari 5.1, Opera 11.5 and Chrome 14 (all the latest versions). I can click on a link to scroll to the corresponding section and scroll or mousewheel around in it.

**Problem:**
In Firefox 7 (and earlier), when I have scrolled to Section 2 or Section 3 and then scroll down **using the scrollbar**, **my position is reset to the first section**. This also happens when I resize the browser window. If I scroll using the mousewheel, Firefox behaves (in other words, I stay in the current section).

My question is pretty much an exact repeat of this question: [Problem mixing overflow-x, FireFox, and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910386/problem-mixing-overflow-x-firefox-and-javascript)

Only, the accepted answer (which is to allow the horizontal scrollbar to be visible) doesn't work for my specific case. Also, the guy who posted the question has removed his example. I really need that scrollbar to stay hidden and I really don't like the idea of hiding it behind a div.

Is there a way (other than setting overflow to "auto") to stop Firefox from resetting my scroll position? Or some other way to hide the scrollbar?

**UPDATE**: Updated Firefox to 8.0 (still a beta version) and then the behaviour is consistent with the other browsers.

Comment: I viewed your example in Chrome 14 & the position is scrolled back to top as well (like FF).

Comment: I can see a couple of options. 1. clip off the scroll bar. Takes some measuring and you have to position absolutely. 2. Add a 2nd div outside that does the vertical scrolling. That breaks your code as it currently stands, but it does resolve the scrolling problem. http://jsfiddle.net/s2YFM/

Comment: @vantrung -cuncon. I'm not sure what you mean. You say: "...in Chrome 14 the position is scrolled back to the top...". Are you referring to a vertical scroll? When does Chrome 14 scroll "to the top"? I have tested the fiddle in Chrome 14 and it behaves correctly. My problem is that my *horizontal* position is reset to the first section when I am in Section 2 or 3 and then use the scrollbar in FF. In Chrome 14 my horizontal position only changes when I click one of the Section links, which is the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Hemlock. Nice one. I've done (1.) for now and clipped the scrollbar out. Your fiddle works nicely, but it'll be a bit harder to use (the real-life site is a bit more involved). I will vote your suggestion up if you provide it as an answer.

Comment: @cfouche Oh, I thought it was the vertical scrollbar. When I scroll the content down, then click another section, the scrollbar of new section auto-scroll to top. Sorry.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon. Relieved that you didn't discover another quirky behaviour. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of options.

1. clip off the scroll bar. Takes some measuring and you have to position absolutely.
2. Add a 2nd div outside that does the vertical scrolling. That breaks your code as it currently stands, but it does resolve the scrolling problem. jsfiddle.net/s2YFM

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same exact issue.  When my "modal window" pops up, I set `html.noscroll { overflow: hidden }`, which unfortunately causes the window to scroll-to-top.

Here's the only solution I could make work:

```
function RemoveScrollbar(html) {
    var scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
    html.addClass('noscroll');
    html.scrollTop = scrollTop;
}
```

This is MooTools code, but super simple to convert to jQuery or other frameworks.